# Cannot Open to Tomcat Manager Screen

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat8

When I try to access the Tomcat Manager page through the browser, it keeps loading but won't open.

> SERVERIP:8080/manager/html

The tomcat service on the server is up. Tomcat version Tomcat 8 If you specify which files are needed, I can add the relevant parts Can you please help me solve my problem? Thank you very much.

tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
  <role rolename="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

My Server credentials

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.79
Server built:   May 16 2022 15:36:23 UTC
Server number:  8.5.79.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.18.0-477.13.1.el8_8.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_372-b07
JVM Vendor:     Red Hat, Inc.
```

I tried to restart tomcat service with `systemctl restart tomcat.service` and reboot linux server but nothing changed.